# What is a Silver Statue good for?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

So I came across a Silver Statue item, with the description "Lacks any real purpose, but can be sold at shops for a good price." Now, some games tell you this and they're honest, but some tell you this and they actually expect you to hold onto it for some reason or another. What kind of game is Paper Jam? Can I safely sell it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiki, it an be sold for 1000 coins, but it can also give you +2 power, defense, speed, and stache.

[source](http://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_clothing_in_Mario_%26_Luigi:_Paper_Jam)

Comment: @Seiyria no problem. happy to help

Comment: For those that come across this, this also applies to Gold Statues. Same thing as Silver Statues, except double the value and stats applied.